# Delete file based on condition

Tags: awk, sh

I have a directory that contain text file and the files are used for some calculation and it produces four column files

Like:

```
0.5000 -0.9650 6.6554 3.4228
```

when column 2 greater than zero and column 3 less than zero then I want to delete that file from folder. I tried script below:

```
#!bin/sh
for file in /home/dew/*.txt
    do
    some calulation for producing four column `file1`
    if awk '{print ($2 > 0 && $3 < 0)}' file1 | rm -rf $file
done
```

But it gives some errors

Comment: Please roll back to your previous question, this is NOT a question at all now. Kindly to revert to your question with details, else future users will NOT get anything from current description.

Comment: Please be aware that the answer you accepted was wrong and has now be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk + xargs`:

```sh
cd /home/dew
awk -v ORS='\0' '$2 > 0 && $3 < 0 {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.txt | 
xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but will `awk` not always exit with status `0`? The default `awk` exit status is `0` unless an error occurred. In the above, the statement `awk '$2 > 0 && $3 < 0 {exit 0}' "$file"` will always return with the exit status `0` and hence, delete all files. If you want to delete based on the condition, you should exit with something else then zero and use `||`. Something more like: `awk '$2 > 0 && $3 < 0 {exit 1}' "$file" || echo rm "$file"`

Comment: Good point @kvantour I have changed it now to do it completely in awk

Comment: Will this not create a race-condition? Trying to read a file that is already deleted? This could lead to unexpected behaviour no?

Comment: In my testing on 6 files in a directory, it didn't. But may be: `awk '$2 > 0 && $3 < 0 {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.txt | xargs rm` ?

Comment: Final update ;-)  `BEGIN{ORS="\000"} .... | xargs -0` for the funny filenames ;-)